# Ternary operator variable and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, security

Will this work?

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
```

I know the ternary operator will work but what about the real escape? And how can I check for future reference if the real escape is successful?

Thanks

Comment: I'd break it out into separate statements rather than do everything inline like that. It's cleaner, easier to read, and easier to add additional logic in there.

Comment: The ternary should be user for simple cases. if you have trouble reading a construct in a ternary, especially with function calls and nested brackets, as you have, then it's too complex and should probably be done as a regular if/then/else.

Comment: Ye I figured but I want to learn how to use these properly :)

Comment: no thats not going to work at all,  obviously you didn't even attempt to run it.

Comment: I ran it and it did work, the ternary did. If you re-read my question I add how to check if the real escape worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is escaping the conditional of the ternary expression not the result.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '');
```

Move the bracket to the end of the expression then you will escape whatever the result of the ternary expression is.  You could also use

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : '';
```

A better option is to use a function for this instead of having a bunch of huge lines of code around ie.

```
function escape_val($arr, $key, $default = ''){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $default);
}

$username = escape_val($_POST, 'username');
$some_other = escape_val($_POST,'key','default_value');
```

Comment: -1 because of your entry-statement which is wrong: "Your code is escaping the boolean value from isset not the string stored in $_POST" - it's wrong because it's giving the wrong information about how the language works - see: [Expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php), [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @hakre:  I rewrote my answer sorry.

Comment: @Basic:  It's one of my favorite PHP snippets.  It saves a massive number of keystrokes and helps avoid having isset calls all over the place.

Comment: Ye it is cool, I never thought of this before, this is going in my functions file. Any ideas on how I can check to see if the real escape is working or not, ie test security?

Comment: @GWW: I see you edited it, but "Your code is escaping the conditional of the ternary expression not the result." is still wrong. The code is not escaping the conditional only, it's escaping the result of the full ternary operator expression. Even more, `escape_val()` would lack the same problem.

Comment: @hakre:  His code is not escaping the whole result it's only escaping the isset portion.  My code escapes the whole result, the point of escaping the whole result in my function is to escape a default value if it's specified.

Comment: @GWWW: My fault I was referring to your code, not the one in the question, so I missed the context of your sentence. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) : '';
//          ^ condition                 ^ value if condition returns true              ^ if false
```