# MySQL Inserting NULL Into Varchar Column

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't I insert `NULL` into a varchar column using MySQL?

PHP:

```
if ($startSemester == "") {
    $startSemester = 'NULL';
}

mysqli_query($gradschool_application_2_connect, "INSERT INTO Application (startSemester) VALUES ('".$startSemester."')");
```

This current code inputs the string `NULL` and not the type. If I remove the single quotes my query will not work.

Comment: Is there a NOT NULL constraint on the column?

Comment: it's got to be `VALUES (NULL)` and not `VALUES('NULL')`. It would be a good idea to use a prepared statement for that.

Comment: Maybe your database fields is set as non-null value?

Comment: Removing quotes around `$startSemester = NULL;` inputs an empty string into the database. There is no NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: Please make the world a better place and don't write code that is massively vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: You may be best using a ternary operator. See this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5626198/ or something like `$var= $_POST['var'] ? '' : '';`

Comment: @Whoa Please, show us the result of the query: `SHOW CREATE TABLE Application;`

Comment: I suggest you set a default value for your column as NULL, and just use a conditional statement such as `if(!empty($variable)){$var="String";}` - I think it's a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-dupe of this one: [MySQL Inserting NULL Value into INT Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045599/mysql-inserting-null-value-into-int-column/26045630#26045630)

You've quoted your NULL string within the query, so you're producing

```
 ... VALUES ('NULL')
```

An SQL null is a keyword, and cannot be quoted

```
[..snip...]) VALUES ('".$startSemester."')");
                     ^------------------^--- remove these quotes
```

Quoting it turns it into a string containing the letters `N`, `U`, `L`, `L`, which when inserted into an int field will simply be typecast to a `0`.

Comment: What if `$startSemester="Some string";`?

Comment: then it's up to the OP to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysqli_query($gradschool_application_2_connect, "INSERT INTO Application (startSemester) VALUES ($startSemester)");
```